# How send graphql query to remote url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, graphql, apollo

Try send by **lokka** to remote url **graphql** query but get

[image]

[image]

I know about CORS and try to add CORS in express

```
app.use(cors());
```

But I do not understand why sends **OPTIONS** instead **POST**

Comment: after using `cors` did the issue got solved??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser sends an `OPTIONS` request first because something in your request triggered it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

That OPTIONS request is formally called a [**CORS-preflight fetch**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch-0) and the CORS protocol *requires* browsers to do it if, e.g., your request includes headers that aren’t [safelisted requests headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header).

Comment: Thus installation **cors** should help?

Comment: Yeah if you have means to configure the server the request is sent to, then you need to configure it to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  response header and other CORS headers and needed. But exactly how you do that depends on what web server and other software you’re running in the server environment.

Comment: I work with express
Try to add ***cors()***
***app.use('/graphql', cors(), graphqlRoute)***
Now I can not say whether it worked

Comment: I add **app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}))**
And add headers

Comment: I don’t know why you’re seeing that message; set `origin: true` in the config object you give to the `cors(…)` call “reflects the request origin” (takes the value of the `Origin` request header and puts it in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header). So I dunno but it guess it might be caused by you having some leftover code somewhere other than that  `cors(…)` call that’s explicitly setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response?